# Mongodb Aggregation with future documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm looking for some guidance on how to best approach this type of query in MongoDB.

I've got a database of purchases, each have a `course` property as well as a date in which the person purchased.

What I want is a list of purchases that happened after someone bought an initial product.

So - some pesudo queries here:

```
// first find everyone who signed up for course A
{ course: 'a' }
```

then

```
/*
  out of those people, filter for those who in the future signed up
  for another course
*/

{
  course: { $in: ['b','c','d']},
  date: { $gt: $courseA.purchaseDate }
}
```

Is this possible with an aggregation? Or would I be making multiple DB calls for each initial purchase to check if there are any future?

Here is some sample of what the data would look like for each purchase:

```
{ email: 'wes@example.com', course: 'a', purchaseDate: 10 },
{ email: 'wes@example.com', course: 'b', purchaseDate: 20 }, // match
{ email: 'wes@example.com', course: 'c', purchaseDate: 5 }, // not
{ email: 'nancy@example.com', course: 'a', purchaseDate: 5 },
{ email: 'nancy@example.com', course: 'c', purchaseDate: 6 }, // match
{ email: 'nancy@example.com', course: 'b', purchaseDate: 10 }, // match
{ email: 'nancy@example.com', course: 'd', purchaseDate: 1 }, // not
```

Comment: Can you post a sample document?

Comment: Just posted an example-  thanks

Comment: instead of approaching the problem like you have described, I suggest doing the below

1. group that so you have one document per user and all the courses they have purchased
2. Filter all users who have NOT purchased course `x`

this will not give you all courses *after* a course but will get you closer

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the answer with some help over on Twitter

```
.aggregate([
  // Project the target purchasedate
  { $match: { course: { $in: ['JS3', 'RDX', 'WTF', 'RFB', 'ES6']}}},
  { $project: {
    email: 1, amount: 1, course: 1, purchaseDate: 1,
    target: {
      $cond: {
        if: { $eq: ['$course', 'JS3'] },
        then: "$purchaseDate",
        else: 0,
      }
    }
  }},
  // Group records by email, storing the target and the highest encountered purchase date
  { $group: {
    _id: '$email',
    courses: { $push: '$course'},
    amounts: { $push: '$amount'},
    count: { $sum: 1 },
    spent: { $sum: '$amount' },
    target: { $first: '$target'},
    max: { $max: '$purchaseDate'}
  }},
  // // Check if the highest encountered date is greater then the target
  { $project: {
    email: 1, course: 1, amounts: 1, spent: 1, count: 1, courses: 1, target:1, max: 1,
    selected: { $cond: [{ $gt: ['$max', '$target']}, true, false] }
  }},
  // Filter out the non-matches
  { $match: {
    target: { $gt: 0 },
    selected: true,
    spent: { $gt: 0 },
  }},
  { $sort: { spent: -1 }}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making a mapReduce like :

```
const options = {
  query: { course: 'courseA' }, // filter only the A course purchased
  map: function(){
    // iterate over course to get the couseA timeStamp

    // for every course you may have here, compare to couseATime
    this.course.forEach(function(course){
       // extract all the timeStamps
    })

    // if courseTime > couseATime then emit
    // emit({_id:this._id, email:this.email}, 1)
  },
  reduce: function(key, val){ // key will be {_id:'', email:''}
    return val // not important
  }
}

Model
  .mapReduce(options)
  .then(function(docs){
  })
```

You should be able to get all the _id & email of people who have bought course != courseA after the date of purchase.

The alternative would be using .aggregate() with .project() and .match but you will have issues getting the courseATimeStamp from different pipeline steps

EDIT:
I assumed course was an array... if course field if a string, this solution could be applied

```
...
// Emit every course with the same key (_id + email)
map(){
  emit({_id: this._id, email:this.email}, {course: this.course, date: this.couse.date})
},

reduce(key, values){
  // key is {_id:'', email:''} and is unique
  // values is an array of {course:'', date:''}
  var aDate
  var dates = []

  // Find other dates
  values.forEach(function(val){
    // isolate course A date => aDate = ...
    // populate dates[] with date + course name
  })

  // dates should be => [{courseB: 10, couseC: 15 ...}]
  // The mean used to saved the couse + date is up to you

  // filter dates $gt aDate
  dates = dates.filter(....)

  return dates
}
```

Notes: Because reduce() is called only if you emit more than one time, you may have so weird result:

- If you emit only one, the result value will the your emited values
- If you emit more than one, the result value will be the filtered array in reduce()

(this make sens if you emit a number, and your reduce also a number — like a total of items)

So, if you need to clean the results, you may want to use the finalize() provided by mongoose.

Comment: What is `this.course`? How does it find the other courses?

Comment: in the map function this represent the current document. So this.course is the "course" field, if this is an array, you can map over